# Buscar proxima data no banco de dados

Tags: php, sql-select

estou criando uma tabela mysql onde contem a data de um evento. A questao  é a seguinte: se caso no dia atual existir um evento ele é destacado caso contrario indica o dia do proximo evento. teriam alguma ideia de como fazer?
A query para o dia atual seria essa mais como buscar a seguinte caso ela não tenha no dia atual.

```
$data_atual = date('Y-m-d');
$resultado_evento = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM agenda WHERE data like '%$data_atual%'");
while($linhas_evento = mysql_fetch_array($resultado_evento)) {
    echo "nome " . $linhas_evento['nome'] . "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use maior igual e ponha um limite para 1, se tiver uma data igual hoje, mostra ela, ou então mostra a próxima data. Não esqueça de dar um ORDER BY pela data.

```
$data_atual = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
$resultado_evento = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM agenda WHERE data >= '$data_atual' ORDER BY data ASC LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: vlw caio pela ajuda, estou iniciando php entao as vezes fico perdidinho com esses selects mais funcionou certinho. abraços

Comment: Legal @Alexandre marque como resposta certa aqui!

Comment: No principio achei ter dado certo mais nao sei o pq, estou usando datatime mais tipo tem um primeiro campo 2016-09-01 14:00 e um segundo 2016-09-01 16:00 mais passando o horario das 14 hrs ou mais  ele continua lendo o primeiro campo e nao passa para o seguinte que seria as 16 hrs tenntei usar a condiçao if mais mesmo assim continua lendo apenas o primeiro campo.

Comment: mais alguma coisa de errado tem no meu codigo, não na chamada, isolei ele em outra pagina e funcionou corretamente. vou verificar se não dupliquei alguma variavel que entrou em conflito

Comment: @Alexandre no $data_atual você precisa colocar a hora então, essa verificação que fiz era apenas com o dia. Editei a resposta

Comment: no select deixei um Hour(data) >= $horas ai ele seleciona apenas da hora atual em diante e se no proximo evento do dia posterior que deveria ser apresentado caso não houvesse nenhum outro evento no dia atual e a hora for menor que no select ela fica anulada até o proximo dia. teria possibilidade de deixar Hour(data) > 00:00:00 ? e qual seria a sintaxe usada no caso?